# Stream NullReferenceException c#

Tags: c#, stream, nullreferenceexception

I don't understand why this exception is thrown. I've seen similar topics but haven't been able to sort it out. Here is my code:

```
static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
      using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("mydll.dll"))
      {
           byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
           stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
           return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
      }
}
```

`stream` is always null when I do `new byte[stream.Length];` and throws exception. Funny thing, this works. But I want to have all the code clean. I've tried checking if the var is null before doing anything or a `while (stream == null) {}`, initialize variables first... but in these cases the dll won't load.

How do I do it?

EDIT: The dll is added to my project and its `build action` is `Content`. As I say, it works, but throws exception...

Comment: If it throws an exception, it is not working

Comment: Clearly you have not configured your resources correctly for the code you are using to retrieve the data. You can call `GetManifestResourceNames()` as a diagnostic technique to investigate what resources exist and what their names are. Note that `Embedded Resource` is typically the build action you want for embedded resources. For further diagnostic help, check the advice provided in the duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look.